# Can regression algorithms treat multiple input features as a single feature for prediction?

Tags: regression, features

I have a regression problem where I have multiple RSSI values from 3 beacons and I need to predict the x & y coordinates of the mobile object sending the signals based on the RSSI values captured by the 3 beacons.

The dataset is as follows:
RSSI values from 3 beacons have been recorded 301 times. However, the timestamp has not been provided so I don't know whether RSSI values coming from 3 beacons at a single time has been recorded or not.

X & y coordinates mobile object sending the signals is given.

My problem does not arise from the scenario.

My question is can regression algorithms like multivariate regression, support vector regression can treat all 301 input features of RSSI values from the three beacons as one whole stack of feature?

Comment: Perhaps you take the average of the 301 features for each of the 3 beacons and try the regression. That way you have 3 features and 1 target.